# Remove the strong name from 3rd party assemblies?

Tags: .net, code-signing, strongname

How can I remove a strong name from a 3rd party assembly that I do not have the source code for, maybe using ilasm/ildasm (since it is possible to [add a strong name using ilasm/ildasm](http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2010/04/23/sign-a-.net-assembly-with-a-strong-name-without-recompiling.aspx))?

Generally, it seems to be possible, since [this tool](http://www.nirsoft.net/dot_net_tools/strong_name_remove.html) seems to be able to do this.

Comment: To answer you original question, yes that's obviously so easy. **Deployed code is by definition unsafe and compromised.** Signing is just one layer of protection (there must be others) for _casual_ crackers.

Comment: XY question, removing a strong name is never necessary.

Comment: @HansPassant I asked this to put together a demo on how easy (or hard) it is to replace a referenced assembly in a 3rd party application. Which can't be done as long as it has a strong name and is referenced by its strong name.

Comment: Well, of course.  If it is was easy then there wouldn't be any point in having strong names.  You have to know the private key, that proves that you are the "owner" of the file and that it hasn't been tampered with.  You want to tamper with it.

Comment: It *is* easy. It a single click with a tool. It removes the strong name of all assmeblies in a folder and redirect the assembly-references to the ones without the strong name. So a strong name is not a valid way to secure that the code you load was not altered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a tool to do it for you, doing it manually will probably take you too much time and hell, if there are tools out there then why reinvent the wheel?

Personally I have never used SNRemove but here is a list of tools I generally use:

- [de4dot](https://github.com/0xd4d/de4dot) - universal .NET deobfuscator/unpacker
- [Strong.Name.Helper v1.7](https://forum.tuts4you.com/files/file/1145-strongnamehelperv17-whoknows-pass-bs7z/)
- [Reflexil](https://github.com/sailro/Reflexil) (plugin for [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/))

---

EDIT: [simple-assembly-explorer/SimpleAssemblyExplorer.Core/Assembler/Assembler.cs](https://github.com/wickyhu/simple-assembly-explorer/blob/8686fe5b82194b091dcfef4d29e78775591258a8/SimpleAssemblyExplorer.Core/Assembler/Assembler.cs) - this class should give you an idea of how strong name keys *can* be removed from strong named assemblies.

Comment: I would like to learn how this is done without an external tool (except the tools that come with .NET itself).

Comment: You will need to use a .NET assembly reader and probably an hex editor. There are no tools shipped with VS/.NET that can be used to remove a strong name.. Removing it by hand is basically fixing up the references, cleaning the assembly and fixing attributes/flags of types that uses signed types.

Comment: Are sure that it is not possible using ilasm/ildasm (which comes with .NET)?

Comment: I am pretty sure ildasm has no functionality to modify strong name verification.. You must understand that removing strong names was never a requirement at Microsoft while developing .NET hence you will not find a tool from the official toolset that does this for you. There is a `sn.exe`  (strong name) inside the same folder as `ildasm.exe` which you can check out but I doubt it will help you get any further.

Answer (score 2):

**This is to remove strong name validation, not remove the strong name signature, however searches for strongname validation errors seem to route to this question so this is not irrelevant.**

[sn.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/sn-exe-strong-name-tool) can be used to disable strongname validation (sn.exe can be accessed via visual studio developer command prompt)

To disable strongname validation for all assemblies with a given public key token:

```
sn.exe -Vr *,<public key hex token>
```

or to disable validation for all assemblies with any public key:

```
sn.exe -Vr *,*
```